# Are parallel hints used in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm porting queries from Oracle to Snowflake and have queries like this:

```
select /*+ parallel(SCHUC)  */
       ...
       schuc.time_period
from some_schuc_table
```

I'm led to believe Snowflake does a better job at spreading workloads, so is it still helpful to supply a parallel hint?

Comment: Snowflake doesn't utilize hints.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide any hint in Snowflake like Oracle. Just shoot the SQL code / stored procedure. The backend snowflake framework will execute in MPP architecture.

And yes, we are seeing Snowflake is running faster than Oracle (at least in our case).